# Couldn't find HOME environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Railside to create a new Rails project. I am on a Mac.

When I do that, I get this error :

```
/Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:12:in `expand_path': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
```

I tried to do this :

```
set HOME=%HOMEPATH%
```

More information :

```
    from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.2/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /Users/justindomingue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what happens when you do "echo ~" (without the quotes) in the terminal?

Comment: BTW you might want to try RubyMine or TextMate.  It's hard to believe they are putting that out as a paid application.  It's not much more than a text editor integrated with a file browser.

Comment: I'm getting this : /Users/justindomingue. Actually, I'm still trying the demo version, I haven't paid yet. I do like the file organisation though (by controlers, config files, etc.)

Comment: Can you create a new rails project on the command line?  `rails new myproject`

Comment: Yes , I can. The problem probably comes from Railside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Railside and have the exact same problem.  Not sure if you already had RVM or if Railside installed it for you.  In my case I already had RVM.  Maybe Railside just doesn't know how to play with RVM.  You could contact them.

However again my suggestion would be to try RubyMine or TextMate instead.  These I think you will find more useful.

BTW any of these tools will organize files for you.  That's in fact one of the benefits of Rails itself.  It's consistent in that this is how the folders are set up in every project (convention over configuration).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will contact them and try Rubymine/Textmate!